# How can we exclude settings in the registry from Windows Restore?

Tags: windows, registry, system-restore

We have some settings we keep in the Windows registry (preferably under HKLM) which shouldn't be deleted or overwritten if the user resets the system to a previous state.
I didn't find a way to manage this. We have to support Windows XP and newer. Any hints?

Comment: You could try creating your own registry hive, additional hives might not be included in restore points.  I suspect this would upset users though.  It would probably be more sensible to store your data in a file instead.